# How can I get input data from the rear touch pad on the Vita?

Tags: c#, mono, playstation

How can I get input data from the rear touch pad on the Vita using Playstation Suite?

I can use:

```
Sce.Pss.Core.Input.Touch.GetData(0)
```

to get data about touches on the screen, does anyone know how to get the touch data from the rear touch panel?

I tried:

```
Sce.Pss.Core.Input.Touch.GetData(1)
```

without any success, I get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Also, could someone with enough rep please add a playstation-suite tag

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), which is probably also why you couldn't find a tag. :-)

Comment: Um, you didn't read what I said. I provided a link to the `game development` StackExchange site, which is probably where you should ask this question instead. :-) You'll probably find the tag you're looking for there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the PS Suite SDK will not, at this time, offer support for the rear touch panel. The SDK is purposed to make games that function on all PS Certified devices, and while this includes the Vita, it also includes a variety of Android devices which lack such an input. They are definitely going for the lowest common denominator here.

[Here is the official response.](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Input/Rear-touch/m-p/14829995#M27)

Really makes a bit more sense why they renamed it PS Mobile. ;)